# How to export clouds made from geometry nodes to unreal?

Tags: export, geometry-nodes, procedural, unreal-engine

I have this cloud [made from geometry nodes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HOR2ZQryTmU). Is it possible to convert it to vdb? Or what would be a better (or possible) way to export them for unreal engine?

[image: Nodes for clouds]

I have tried fbx - but that doesn't bring anything. Not even a stack of boxes.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: I would suggest splitting the Question in two because geometry nodes and shaders are two vastly different systems that will require individual solutions. And please also pay attention to Duarte Farrajota Ramos comment.

Comment: I had a similar problem resolved [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/298078/how-do-i-get-my-grid-with-geometry-nodes-used-to-distribute-objects-imported-int/298232#298232) that might help with your problem