# How do I get my grid with geometry nodes used to distribute objects imported into Unreal Engine?

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes

I have laid a collection, that includes garbage bags, over a grid as you can see in the picture
[image]
I did this using Geometry Nodes with the following setup:
[image]

How do I get the combination of the grid+garbage_bags into Unreal Engine? I tried exporting as a .fbx file, but when I import the .fbx file into UE, it doesn't import the plastic bags. It only imports the grid.

This is my "View Layer" in case it is helpful:

[image]

Comment: So what do you want for the bottom part? It's not clear, do you mean the bags are supposed to be cut off?

Comment: @moonboots Yes, that could work but I couldn't find how to do it. I added a few more sentences to clarify further. I will use this by taking pictures from above and that's why I only care about the top part. Any other way to have a similar result?

Comment: why do you need to cut away the bottom when you will never see it from the top? nobody views the bottom anyway. why would it matter?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie It's because I'm pretty sure I can't import it in Unreal Engine otherwise.  I could go in detail about everything I tried but's it's a bit out of scope for now. Basically, it imports the grid but not the objects due to them being distributed through Geometry Nodes. So, a way to resolve it would be with taking the top part.

Comment: @AthanasiosPetsanis well it's not really out of scope explaining the situation because otherwise this would be considered an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) type of question.

Comment: As Harry mentions, this sounds like the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me as well. If you can't import you model because it was generated with geometry nodes, then you should look into solutions for that issue. I don't see how removing the bottom part could help with that, it seems completely unrelated and even a poor decision overall.

Comment: The problem here is not the underside of the bags and not only that the bags are generated by _Geometry Nodes_, which is a modifier that is not supported by Unreal Engine - like other modifiers as well e.g. _Subdivision Surface_ or _Bevel_ etc., the modifier has to be applied to convert everything to a mesh to export it for UE. But the bags are not real objects in _Geometry Nodes_ yet, they are instances and will disappear when you apply the modifier. Therefore you have to put a _Realize Instances_ node after the _Instance on Points_ node before applying the modifier.

Comment: HarryMcKenzie , DuarteFarrajotaRamos , as you say this is the XY Problem. I asked this question because I wanted to address a way I thought could solve my root problem, but did not ask about the root problem.

@GordonBrinkmann This fixed it! Thank you all very much.

Should I edit this question as asking my root problem or should I post another question? I think this answer could be helpful for other people as well.

Comment: @AthanasiosPetsanis Usually we encourage people here to edit their questions to get them re-opened. It is not necessary to post a new question for basically the same problem. I was about to answer the question, but couldn't because it was closed.

Comment: @Athanasios could you edit your post to rephrase your issue and aak to reopen  so Gordon can post an answer

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Yes of course! I will do so within the day.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann It is opened again, answer away ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to export your grid with the garbage bags to FBX, it first of all is important to apply the *Geometry Nodes* modifier since it is not supported by the FBX format. Conveniently you usually do not have to do this before exporting since in the export settings under *Geometry* > *Apply Modifiers* is enabled by default, that's why your grid would appear in the FBX even if it would have been created in *Geometry Nodes*:

[image: apply modifiers upon export]

But the garbage bags are missing. So, although the modifier is applied upon export, to avoid a rude awakening when importing the FBX it might be useful to apply it before exporting to see if everything is correct (but of course you might want to undo this operation after export to still be able to edit the *Geometry Nodes* afterwards).

Anyway, the reason the garbage bags do not show up is that they are instances and not real mesh objects. To keep them after the modifier gets applied to have to plug a *Realize Instances* node after the *Instance on Points* node:

[image: realized instances]

By the way, a clear indicator that there are instances which might not show up after applying the modifier without the need to actually do that is the orange selection outline. In the above image you can see that the outline goes around the complete object like it is just one mesh object - even if there was a gap between parts, rotating the view so that they overlap should show a mutual outline.

In the image below you see how it looks like without realizing the instances - each instanced object has its own separate outline. And although in other scenarios it might not be clear which object is an instance and which a mesh object, separate outlines at least show that there are objects which will disappear after applying the modifier.

[image: separate instances]